# How to make this HTML + CSS code mobile-friendly or at least hide it in mobile if it doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling to make this code mobile friendly or at least hide it entirely in mobile.. Please tell me what should I do now with this code? When opened in mobile, it looks exactly same as in the desktop version. I tried everything, but it won't just work for me unfortunately : (

```css
<head><style>* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cg-row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cg-container-fluid-xs {
  min-width: 704px;
  max-width: 1376px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: calc(20px - .5rem);
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c-promo-container___3jmaq {
  padding: 16px 0 46px;
}

  
section {
  display: block;
}

#mainpage___R6E7C {
  min-width: 992px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

html {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Lato, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #121212;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.cg-col-1,
.cg-col-10,
.cg-col-11,
.cg-col-12,
.cg-col-13,
.cg-col-14,
.cg-col-15,
.cg-col-16,
.cg-col-17,
.cg-col-18,
.cg-col-19,
.cg-col-2,
.cg-col-20,
.cg-col-21,
.cg-col-22,
.cg-col-23,
.cg-col-24,
.cg-col-3,
.cg-col-4,
.cg-col-5,
.cg-col-6,
.cg-col-7,
.cg-col-8,
.cg-col-9 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.cg-col-12 {
  width: calc(50% - .5rem);
}

.cg-col-6 {
  width: calc(25% - .5rem);
}

.c-promo-block___2xszw {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.c-promo-info-block-map___2_cMd {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(../h/27d6983bf2e347e8e369a48cf6c8104f.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  padding: 0;
}

.c-promo-info-block-map-content___mboJV {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .5), hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9) 35%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9) 65%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .5));
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .5), hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9) 35%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9) 65%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .5));
  padding-top: 37px;
}

.c-promo-info-map-text___1NaCE,
.c-promo-info-map-title___2oRJ2 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #121212;
}

.c-promo-info-map-title___2oRJ2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.27;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.c-promo-info-map-text___1NaCE {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.38;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

a {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}

.c-link-default___3PDtU {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2b87db;
  min-height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s, border-color .3s, background .3s;
  transition: color .3s, border-color .3s, background .3s;
}

.c-promo-info-map-button___-lfOt {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 28px;
  width: 135px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.8;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  color: #2b87db;
  border: 1px solid rgba(43, 135, 219, .5);
}

.c-promo-block-image___3jLUE {
  height: 200px;
  width: 49.35%;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.c-promo-block-image-left___3Hwgv .c-promo-block-image___3jLUE {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.c-promo-block-text___2UJtj {
  height: 200px;
  width: 49.35%;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.c-promo-block-image-left___3Hwgv .c-promo-block-text___2UJtj {
  float: right;
}

.c-promo-block-text-content___3DvyN {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  padding: 17px 16px 12px 24px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c-promo-title___2h2NK {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #121212;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 3px;
}

.c-promo-list___ArSBG {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.c-promo-list___ArSBG li {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.c-promo-count____oRq1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.c-promo-block-image-content___30WAj {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.c-promo-catalog-list___3ubrJ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 12px;
}

.c-promo-catalog-list-item___7f58O {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 10px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.c-promo-block-image-none___3ahNN .c-promo-block-text___2UJtj {
  width: 100%;
}

.c-promo-block-image-right___2cjDj .c-promo-block-image___3jLUE {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.c-promo-block-image-right___2cjDj .c-promo-block-text___2UJtj {
  float: left;
}

.c-promo-block-image-hide___25WnG .c-promo-block-image___3jLUE {
  display: block;
}

.c-promo-block-image-hide___25WnG .c-promo-block-text___2UJtj {
  width: 49.35%;
}

</style></head>
```

```html
<body>
  <main class="mainpage" id="mainpage">
    <section id="mainpage___R6E7C" data-reactroot="" data-react-checksum="699345249" data-reactid="1">
      <div data-reactid="3">
        <div class="c-promo-container___3jmaq" data-reactid="46">
          <div class="cg-container-fluid-xs" data-reactid="47">
            <div class="cg-row undefined" data-reactid="48">
              <div class="c-promo-block___2xszw c-promo-block-image-left___3Hwgv undefined cg-col-12 cg-col-promo-s-16___wTgkf cg-col-xs-16" data-reactid="49">
                <div class="c-promo-block-image___3jLUE" data-reactid="50">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-image-content___30WAj" style='background-image: url("//cdn.site/frontend/mainpage/h/3ba3cd60ad320906069256c2da90b6c6.jpg");' data-reactid="51">
                    <div class="c-promo-catalog-list___3ubrJ" data-reactid="52"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="c-promo-block-text___2UJtj" data-reactid="53">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-text-content___3DvyN" data-reactid="54">
                    <h5 class="c-promo-title___2h2NK" data-reactid="55">Купить квартиру</h5>
                    <ul class="c-promo-list___ArSBG" data-reactid="56">
                      <li data-reactid="57"><a title="Продажа однокомнатных квартир в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.ru/kupit-1-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/" data-reactid="58">1-комнатные</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="59">30 869</span></li>
                      <li
                        data-reactid="60"><a title="Продажа двухкомнатных квартир в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.ru/kupit-2-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/" data-reactid="61">2-комнатные</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="62">42 677</span></li>
                        <li
                          data-reactid="63"><a title="Продажа трехкомнатных квартир в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.ru/kupit-3-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/" data-reactid="64">3-комнатные</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="65">37 819</span></li>
                          <li
                            data-reactid="66"><a title="Продажа квартир со свободной планировкой в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.ru/kupit-kvartiru-svobodnoy-planirovki/" data-reactid="67">Свободная планировка</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1"
                              data-reactid="68">4 032</span></li>
                            <li data-reactid="69"><a title="Продажа квартир-студий в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/kupit-kvartiru-studiu/" data-reactid="70">Квартиры-студии</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="71">2 291</span></li>
                            <li
                              data-reactid="72"><a title="Продажа комнат в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/kupit-komnatu/" data-reactid="73">Комнаты в квартире</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="74">2 043</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="c-promo-block___2xszw c-promo-block-image-left___3Hwgv c-promo-block-image-hide___25WnG cg-col-12 cg-col-promo-s-8___1bx1B cg-col-xs-8" data-reactid="75">
                <div class="c-promo-block-image___3jLUE" data-reactid="76">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-image-content___30WAj" style='background-image: url("//cdn.cian.site/frontend/mainpage/h/d5979ff95c209d650eb2cc002d7143f0.jpg");' data-reactid="77">
                    <div class="c-promo-catalog-list___3ubrJ" data-reactid="78"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="c-promo-block-text___2UJtj" data-reactid="79">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-text-content___3DvyN" data-reactid="80">
                    <h5 class="c-promo-title___2h2NK" data-reactid="81">Снять квартиру</h5>
                    <ul class="c-promo-list___ArSBG" data-reactid="82">
                      <li data-reactid="83"><a title="Аренда однокомнатных квартир в Москве на длительный срок" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-1-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/" data-reactid="84">1-комнатные</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1"
                          data-reactid="85">5 784</span></li>
                      <li data-reactid="86"><a title="Аренда двухкомнатных квартир в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-2-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/" data-reactid="87">2-комнатные</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="88">9 324</span></li>
                      <li
                        data-reactid="89"><a title="Аренда трехкомнатных квартир в Москве на длительный срок" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-3-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/" data-reactid="90">3-комнатные</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1"
                          data-reactid="91">8 316</span></li>
                        <li data-reactid="92"><a title="Аренда квартир-студий в Москве на длительный срок" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-kvartiru-studiu/" data-reactid="93">Квартиры-студии</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="94">104</span></li>
                        <li
                          data-reactid="95"><a title="Аренда комнат в Москве на длительный срок" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-komnatu/" data-reactid="96">Комнаты в квартире</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="97">3 609</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="c-promo-block___2xszw c-promo-block-image-right___2cjDj undefined cg-col-12 cg-col-promo-s-16___wTgkf cg-col-xs-16" data-reactid="98">
                <div class="c-promo-block-image___3jLUE" data-reactid="99">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-image-content___30WAj" style='background-image: url("//cdn.cian.site/frontend/mainpage/h/07cc3ef1de2628ef36310f88c361769c.jpg");' data-reactid="100">
                    <div class="c-promo-catalog-list___3ubrJ" data-reactid="101"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="c-promo-block-text___2UJtj" data-reactid="102">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-text-content___3DvyN" data-reactid="103">
                    <h5 class="c-promo-title___2h2NK" data-reactid="104">Снять посуточно</h5>
                    <ul class="c-promo-list___ArSBG" data-reactid="105">
                      <li data-reactid="106"><a title="Снять квартиру посуточно в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-kvartiru-posutochno/" data-reactid="107">Квартиры посуточно</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="108">3 511</span></li>
                      <li
                        data-reactid="109"><a title="Снять коттедж на сутки в Московской области" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-kottedzh-posutochno-moskovskaya-oblast/" data-reactid="110">Коттеджи на сутки</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1"
                          data-reactid="111">1 186</span></li>
                        <li data-reactid="112"><a title="Снять комнату посуточно в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-komnatu-posutochno/" data-reactid="113">Комнаты на сутки</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="114">174</span></li>
                        <li
                          data-reactid="115"><a class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=rent&amp;engine_version=2&amp;offer_type=flat&amp;region=1&amp;room10=1&amp;type=1" data-reactid="116">Хостелы</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1"
                            data-reactid="117">503</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="c-promo-block___2xszw c-promo-block-image-none___3ahNN undefined cg-col-6 cg-col-promo-s-8___1bx1B cg-col-xs-8" data-reactid="118">
                <div class="c-promo-block-text___2UJtj" data-reactid="119">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-text-content___3DvyN" data-reactid="120">
                    <h5 class="c-promo-title___2h2NK" data-reactid="121">Новостройки</h5>
                    <ul class="c-promo-list___ArSBG" data-reactid="122">
                      <li data-reactid="123"><a title="Квартиры в новостройках (ЖК) в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/novostroyki/" data-reactid="124">Каталог ЖК</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="125">1 167</span></li>
                      <li
                        data-reactid="126"><a title="Сданные новостройки (ЖК) в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/novostroyki-na-stadii-sdachi/" data-reactid="127">Сданные новостройки</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="128">723</span></li>
                        <li
                          data-reactid="129"><a title="Строящиеся жилые комплексы (ЖК) в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/novostroyki-stroyashiesya/" data-reactid="130">Строящиеся новостройки</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1"
                            data-reactid="131">634</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="c-promo-block___2xszw c-promo-block-image-none___3ahNN undefined cg-col-6 cg-col-promo-s-8___1bx1B cg-col-xs-8" data-reactid="132">
                <div class="c-promo-block-text___2UJtj" data-reactid="133">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-text-content___3DvyN" data-reactid="134">
                    <h5 class="c-promo-title___2h2NK" data-reactid="135">Загородная недвижимость</h5>
                    <ul class="c-promo-list___ArSBG" data-reactid="136">
                      <li data-reactid="137"><a title="Купить дом, коттедж в Подмосковье" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/kupit-dom-moskovskaya-oblast/" data-reactid="138">Купить дом</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="139">52 432</span></li>
                      <li
                        data-reactid="140"><a title="Купить таунхаус в Московской области" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/kupit-taunhaus-moskovskaya-oblast/" data-reactid="141">Купить таунхаус</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="142">3 298</span></li>
                        <li
                          data-reactid="143"><a title="Купить земельный участок в Подмосковье" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/kupit-zemelniy-uchastok-moskovskaya-oblast/" data-reactid="144">Купить участок</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1"
                            data-reactid="145">32 479</span></li>
                          <li data-reactid="146"><a title="Снять коттедж в Москве и Подмосковье" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-dom-moskovskaya-oblast/" data-reactid="147">Снять дом надолго</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="148">6 987</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="c-promo-block___2xszw c-promo-block-image-left___3Hwgv undefined cg-col-12 cg-col-promo-s-16___wTgkf cg-col-xs-16" data-reactid="149">
                <div class="c-promo-block-image___3jLUE" data-reactid="150">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-image-content___30WAj" style='background-image: url("//cdn.cian.site/frontend/mainpage/h/aef23a51dbe3327ccd3046369c77d228.jpg");' data-reactid="151">
                    <div class="c-promo-catalog-list___3ubrJ" data-reactid="152"><a class="c-link-default___3PDtU c-promo-catalog-list-item___7f58O" href="https://www.cian.ru/snyat-pomeshenie-v-biznes-centre/" data-reactid="153">Каталог бизнес-центров</a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="c-promo-block-text___2UJtj" data-reactid="154">
                  <div class="c-promo-block-text-content___3DvyN" data-reactid="155">
                    <h5 class="c-promo-title___2h2NK" data-reactid="156">Коммерческая недвижимость</h5>
                    <ul class="c-promo-list___ArSBG" data-reactid="157">
                      <li data-reactid="158"><a title="Продажа складов и складских помещений в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/kupit-sklad/" data-reactid="159">Купить склад</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="160">177</span></li>
                      <li
                        data-reactid="161"><a title="Купить гараж в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/kupit-garazh/" data-reactid="162">Купить гараж</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="163">1 915</span></li>
                        <li data-reactid="164"><a title="Купить офис в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.cian.ru/kupit-ofis/" data-reactid="165">Купить офис</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="166">4 116</span></li>
                        <li data-reactid="167"><a title="Снять офис в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.ru/snyat-ofis/" data-reactid="168">Арендовать офис</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="169">31 963</span></li>
                        <li data-reactid="170"><a title="Снять помещение свободного назначения в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.ru/snyat-pomeshenie-svobodnogo-naznachenija/" data-reactid="171">Арендовать помещение</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1"
                            data-reactid="172">9 455</span></li>
                        <li data-reactid="173"><a title="Аренда торговых помещений в Москве" class="c-link-default___3PDtU undefined" href="https://www.ru/snyat-torgovuyu-ploshad/" data-reactid="174">Арендовать торговую площадь</a><span class="c-promo-count____oRq1" data-reactid="175">8 465</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="c-promo-info-block-map___2_cMd cg-col-12 cg-col-promo-s-24___2jQGy cg-col-xs-24">
                <div class="c-promo-info-block-map-content___mboJV"><span class="c-promo-info-map-title___2oRJ2">Поиск на карте</span><span class="c-promo-info-map-text___1NaCE"><!-- react-text: 585 -->Ищите новостройки рядом с работой,<!-- /react-text --><br><!-- react-text: 587 --> парком или родственниками<!-- /react-text --></span>
                  <a
                    class="c-link-default___3PDtU c-promo-info-map-button___-lfOt" href="//map.cian.ru/?deal_type=2&amp;engine_version=2&amp;newbuildings_search=true">Найти на карте</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: This does not look like you tried everything. There's not even a `@media` query here, the most basic building block for responsive CSS.

Comment: @ulviruatamli , did you add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `head` ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with media query?
This example down here show you how with a screen less than 600px width the background will be blue for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

In your case you can just wrap everything in a div and define it as hidden under a certain width.

Answer (score 0):

Add below tag in the `<head>...</head>` section of your html page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

You need to use CSS media queries to manage the content for different viewport.

You can learn css media queries from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Hope this may help you.